# D3 javascript pulling data from mysql Uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, d3.js

Im currently getting my data from a mysql database using this php :

```
<?php
    $username = "*****"; 
    $password = "******";   
    $host = "localhost";
    $database="db";

    $server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

    $myquery = "
SELECT  `this`, `that` FROM  `table`
";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysql_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }

    $fp = fopen('empdata.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
    fclose($fp);    

    mysql_close($server);
?>
```

I then run this html with the previous json file that I generated

```
d3.json("mypreviouslygeneratedjson.json", function (error, data) {

    data.forEach(function (d) 
    {
        ...
    }
...
```

It all goes well, I can generate bar charts, pie charts etc. But as soon as I replace the 3 fopen,fwrite and fclose lines with this line:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

(plus I replace "mypreviouslygeneratedjson.json" with the php file that I mentioned before)

As soon as I try to do this, I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

What is going on here? Im practically using the same json in both cases.

Comment: you tried console logging the data ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy when I console log the data inside the d3.json I get nothing. When I run the php , I get the data echoed on the webpage.

Comment: how about passing the data to a variable and when you run the php just set the variable to the new data ? Then just get rid of the d3.json line

Comment: @thisOneGuy how can I do that? Im pretty new to php and php/js combinations.

Comment: I haven't used php, but I am guessing you just attach the returned data to a variable then pass this variable to D3. I would recommend having an update function which runs your D3 visualization so you can update it with new data on the fly. Have a look at D3 enter() and exit() or just look at update d3 layout with new data on google :)

Comment: @thisOneGuy Ok thank you!! I will search into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the json generated by my php file included the following mysql warning in it :

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

This resulted in filling my json file with html, making it unreadable by the d3.json